# Powershell set Attributes sh when name starts with ~

Tags: powershell, attributes, filenames, hidden

I need to write a script that goes recursive through several hundred directories and if it finds a file beginning with "~", the hidden and system attribute should be set at that file.

So far I got this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test\~* - Recurse | foreach {$_.Attributes = 'Hidden, System'}
```

But it only seems to change the first file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the `-Filter` parameter to find files beginning with `~`.
- Add the `-File` switch to exclude directories.
- Remove the space between `-` and `Recurse`

This should work:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\test\' -Filter '~*' -Recurse -File | foreach {
    $_.Attributes = 'Hidden, System'
}
```

Comment: thank you - just the -file didn't work. But this was perfect for my needs

Answer (score -1):

Do something like `dir c:\ -recurse | ? Name -match "~"`, that gets you all with the ~ in. Then set the attribute like you are.

Comment: He wants to get only files that **beginn** with a `~`. You match all files **AND** directories that contains a `~` **anywhere**. Its also not performant to apply the filter **after** you retrieved all items.